# yum don't see libEMF when Installing dia on CentOS 7.0

Tags: linux, dia, centos7

I'm installing dia on CentOS 7.0.
Command:

```
[root@localhost dima]# yum install dia
```

Error message:

```
Error: Package: 1:dia-0.97.2-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
       Requires: libEMF.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:dia-0.97.2-1.el6.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
       Requires: libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit)
```

I found that libEMF could be installed from epel repository. I have this repository too, but when I tried to install libEMF, I got message "package not found, nothing to install". Then I found this package here: http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libEMF.so.1, but this site has package only for centOS 6.5, not for 7.0. I istalled libEMF from that source, but nothing changed. Now I have required file:

```
[root@localhost dima]# find / -name libEMF.so.1
/usr/lib/libEMF.so.1
```

But when I try to install dia again, I receive the same error message as before.
Also I have python 2.7 installed and I don't understand, what I need to do to get libpython2.6.so.1.0. I don't want to downgrade python from 2.7 to 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to install an EL6 (CentOS/RHEL 6) package for dia, rather than an EL7 package, this is why you are getting dependencies for Python 2.6 and CentOS 6 versions of libEMF. It looks like you are using RPMforge/RepoForge which doesn't appear to have EL7 packages. EPEL does, but I don't see a dia package for EL7 from EPEL either; they do have one for EL6.

Update October 2017: EPEL now has a dia package for EL7.

Answer (score 0):

Just download dia for fedora 19
ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/archive.fedoraproject.org/fedora/linux/releases/19/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/d/dia-0.97.2-5.fc19.x86_64.rpm
just install it.
I hope that help you.